# Cannot store localstorage values via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, local-storage

Please help,
I have a dynamically generated set of button-incremented inputs. First i store id's and values into localstorage, and everything goes fine and i can see all the id-value pairs, but i cannot send the data using AJAX call.
Here's what it looks like:

The AJAX is assigned on button click:

```
<script>
        $("#send_order").click(function (e) {
            if (localStorage) {
                if (localStorage.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                        var pid = localStorage.key(i);
                        var value = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));

                        $.ajax({                                
                            url: "update.php?pid="+pid+"&qty="+value,
                            success: function(){
                                alert( "Прибыли данные: ");
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    output += 'Нет сохраненных данных.';
                }
            } else {
                output += 'Ваш браузер не поддерживает локальное хранилище.';
            }
            )};
    </script>
```

But nothing happens when the button is clicked.
What i do wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me :) I'm using Chrome 40.0.2214.111 (latest)

Comment: Any error in console? Put a breakpoint and step through code And inspect variables?

Comment: I see you are doing an ajax call in a loop. Don't you think it is more efficient to send your localstorage array at once (only one ajax call)?

Comment: are you sure that your browser in which you're testing supports localStorage ? did u check in DevTools -> Network if any Ajax call is actually fired ?

Answer (score 1):

While your code looks fine it is little inefficient to send your localstorage data one by one in a loop. It makes more sense to convert your localstorage to a json string and send everything at the same time. You can [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json string in your php update script. Also I included a function to test if `localStorage` is available by trying to write in it. This is more reliable then `if(localStorage)`

```
 $("#send_order").on("click", function () {   
    var output='';
    if(localStorageTest() === true){
        console.log('localStorage is available');
        if(localStorage.length){
            var data=JSON.stringify(localStorage);
            $.ajax({ 
                    type: "GET",                               
                    url: "update.php?data="+data,
                    success: function(){
                               alert( "your data is send correctly!");
                    }
            }); 

        }else{
           output += 'localStorage is empty\n';     
        }
    }else{
        output += 'localStorage is not available\n';
    }
})

function localStorageTest(){
    var test = "test";
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(test, test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `This is more reliable then if(localStorage)`. I'll have to disagree with you on this :) What the OP is doing is called feature testing and it's by far the easiest and best way to check if a browser supports some feature

Comment: @Arkantos: sorry but you are wrong. older browsers may evaluate if(localStorage) as true while localStorage isn't available. See modernizers source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/storage/localstorage.js

Comment: @kasper Taeymans..  I didn't know that it might throw an exception if its disabled or the iOS issue, thanks for pointing out :-)